# Enforcing implicit relationships in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm having a hard time figuring out if there is a way to enforce implicit relationsships in SQL when creating your database structure. On an abstract level, I want to model something like the following:

A **Person** can belong to one or many **Workfield**'s, a workfield can have one or many **Sub-workfield**'s which a person can also belong to. If a person belongs to one or more sub-workfield's, then he must also belong to their parent workfield's.

Is there a way to enforce this relationship in SQL or do I need to do this in the application layer?

Answer (score 2):

You can enforce this in the database.  One method is to have four tables:  `Person`, `Workfield`, `Subworkfield`, and `PersonWorks`.

The first three are pretty self-explanatory.  The `Subworkfield` table would have a column `WorkfieldId` that would have a foreign key relationship to `Workfield`.  The column `Subworkfield.SubworkfieldId` would be the primary key, and the column pair `SubworkfieldId, WorkfieldId` would be declared `unique`.  This latter declaration is redundant but it is helpful for enforcing one of the conditions.

The `Personworks` table would have three (relevant) columns:

- PersonId references Person(PersonId)
- WorkfieldId references Workfield(WorkfieldId)
- SubworkfieldId references Subworkfield(SubworkfieldId)

Each would have a foreign references as suggested.  When the reference is to `Workfield` only, then `SubworkfieldId` would be `NULL`.

In addition, there would be more one more foreign key reference:

```
foreign key (WorkfieldId, SubworkfieldId) referenes SubworkfieldId(WorkfieldId, SubWorkfieldId)
```

And, for completeness, you might add:

```
check (WorkfieldId is not null)
```

This structure takes advantage of how `NULL` values are handled for foreign key references.  If the key or any part of a composite key is `NULL`, then the foreign key reference is not checked.  Hence, you can have the reference to the `Subworkfield` table, and it is only used when the data is populated.

Comment: Thanks, definetely food for thought!